# How do I prevent the "parenthesis after method name" warning from ruby -w

Tags: ruby, warnings

I would like to have my script able to run without warnings. What is the proper Ruby syntax to avoid warnings like this? *Thanks! --Myles*

```
def absolutize_all_config_var_paths (in_var)
  ...
end

ruby -w ./scripts/run_flow
./scripts/run_flow:742: warning: parentheses after method name is interpreted as an argument list, not a decomposed argument
```

Ruby version `ruby 2.4.1p111`

Comment: You can suppress the warning by adding `-W0` to the command line or setting one of the global variables `$-v`, `$-w` , `$VERBOSE` to `nil`. Why one would want to mask potential errors, however, is beyond me. Better to fix the code so the warning doesn't appear.

Comment: Good information. But I don't want to mask the warnings. I'm willing to go with the flow. I just wanted confirmation on what The Flow is. Thanks Cary! [Separate problem: I have to use $VERBOSE=nil to prevent the incessant warnings about insecure world writable directories in my path. But that's a different question.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space between the method name and opening bracket:

```
def absolutize_all_config_var_paths(in_var)
  ...
end
```

Comment: I've always used the convention of using a space when declaring functions (or methods) and no space when calling them. Looks like The Ruby Way is to not use a space when declaring. I will edit my code to conform. Thanks! http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/

Comment: ...or remove the parentheses.

Comment: @MylesPrather I was doing it just as you've been doing it and IMHO it sucks if a language forces code style on you, thus for me Ruby has just fallen massively in my esteem.